# What is the "correct" pronunciation of Princess Leia's name?

Tags: star-wars

A colleague with the same name recently pointed out that in a New Hope the pronunciation "Lee-ah" is used. However, in later movies, "Lay-ah" is more common.

What is the correct pronunciation of Princess Leia's name? Are there any out-of-universe comments by George Lucas referencing this?

Comment: @Skooba Grand Moff Tarkin as well.

Comment: @MgSam British. Doesn't count!

Comment: Carrie Fisher doesn't seem to be able to decide if it's "lee-yah" or "Lay-yah". She uses both interchangeably; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kh1t2MJDbrs

Comment: THROAT-wobbler MAN-grove.

Comment: Depends if you're in the European or American section of the galaxy.  Just ask [Nicholas Wirth](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Niklaus_Wirth)

Comment: I felt that my answer was about as comprehensive as you get, considering it's an actual pronunciation guide.

Answer (score 44):

The people closest to Leia (in-universe) and that appear later (out-of-universe) all pronounce her name the same way: **LAY-uh**.

However, it does seem at the time *A New Hope* was filmed and released the pronunciation may have been; **LEE-ah**.

---

### Evidence:

**[*Episode III*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DeoGfNEGVS0)**

In the scene where Padme gives birth, Obi-Wan asks her to name the children.  At about 0:47 in the video Leia is born. Padme clearly pronounces it *LAY-uh*.

---

**[*Episode IV*](http://www.starwars.com/video/destruction-of-alderaan)** Just prior the destruction of Alderaan, Leia and Tarkin have an exchange. Tarkin pronounces the name *LEE-uh*

[Destruction of Alderaan on Disney Video](http://www.starwars.com/video/destruction-of-alderaan)

Also, Senator Dodonna uses the *LEE-uh* pronounciation during the briefing prior the assault on the Death Star. Heard at about 0:11.

---

**[*Episode V*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xu5-hq-h_4Q)**

Luke calls out to Leia vocally but is trying to use the Force. He uses the *LAY-uh* pronunciation. See this around 0:50.

---

**[*Episode VI*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MDYX_PgorRY)**

When Luke is talking to her about their mother he pronounces it *LAY-uh*. This occurs at about 0:04.

---

**[*Epsiode VII*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQ_Q0EsGs-Y)**

When Leia and Han reunited, Han pronounces it *LAY-uh* at about 1:24.

---

**Out-of-universe:** *Episode IV* was the first film released and seems to be the only place where the name is pronounce "Lee-uh".  Newer movies all have the same pronunciation, so it appears that a decision was made to either change or standardize her name after the first film.

In many interviews from the time period the pronunciation is also *LAY-uh* by the hosts and the actors: here is one example of Carrie Fisher doing just that at about 1:07

Comment: `Tarkin pronounces the name LEE-uh ` Aha! So that's the derogatory pronunciation!

Comment: You should add that Leia pronounces her own name as *LAY-uh* when she first meets Lando in Episode V. To me, that's the strongest evidence for the pronunciation.

Comment: Your second-to-last video link is dead.

Comment: For all your in-universe examples: Family (Mother, Brother, Husband) pronounces it "LAY-uh", everyone else says "LEE-uh".

Comment: "A New Hope" wasn't so much filmed as concocted in the 1981 out of the original _Star Wars_ movie for re-release.

Answer (score 19):

The (canon) Star Wars factbook [Star Wars Made Easy: A Beginner's Guide to a Galaxy Far, Far Away](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Made_Easy) includes a handy pronunciation guide.

> [image: Leia from the factbook]
> <sub><sup>Caption reads *"Leia Organa - LAY-ah or-GAH-nah"*</sup></sub>

Comment: Now if this isn't acccurate I don't know what is

Comment: Them eyes man... freaking me out man....

Answer (score 16):

George Lucas pronounces it as "Lee-ah".

Given he directed the *A New Hope*, but not *Empire Strikes Back* or *Return of the Jedi*, it's easily possible that he controlled how the actors pronounced it in the first film but it was not discussed in the next two. By the time *Revenge of the Sith* and later movies had come out, pop-culture had already settled upon the "Lay-uh" pronunciation.

Comment: Yeah, and thank goodness. Lucas also said that Greedo shot first and he was overridden by pop culture there too.

Comment: @matrixugly If it wasn't for George Lucas we wouldn't be discussing Star Wars right now.

Answer (score 11):

It was originally pronounced Lee-ah, not Lay-ah, in 1977's original release of *Star Wars* before all the director's cuts.  Both Grand Moff Tarkin, and the Rebel alliance commander clearly pronounce Leia's name as Lee-ah.

The first pronunciation of Lay-ah, publicly, that I recall was on the first run of Kenner action figure toy releases, circa 1978, when the TV commercial voiceover pronounced it Lay-ah.  We, original *Star Wars* fans, in the school yard thought it was a mistake in the TV voiceover's pronunciation but then her name was pronounced Lay-ah from *Empire Strikes Back* onwards.

Therefore, it seems that George Lucas was already confusing Star Wars's fan base with disjointed continuity from the very start!

**My Source**: I was there!  I'm an original 10 year old *Star Wars* fan who was obsessed with the movie after seeing it in its original format (before it was called *Episode IV: A New Hope*) in the theaters five times in 1977. I had the toys, fan magazines, T-shirts, memorized the movies lines, etc.